# Unexpected result php fmod

Tags: php, html

Here is my code below

```
echo 20*0.01;    

echo round(fmod('0.017','0.01'),2);
```

ideally second one should display `0` but its displaying `6.9388939039072E-18` ..Iam aware `fmod` is not ideal to use in this case sometimes it displays 'unexpected' output.. but how to fix this?? I am just looking for an answer....Iam actually not worried about the reason on why the output is `6.9388939039072E-18`..

Comment: `what is this` -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: do u have any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php#Hcom42066):

> Modulus with non integer numbers will give unpredictable results.

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php#Hcom42066) says:

> Note that operator % (modulus) works just with integers (between
>   -214748348 and 2147483647) while fmod() works with short and large numbers.

Comment: Frankly speaking iam not worried about `6.9388939039072E-18` i just need the solution to fix this... atleast you should have added your answer in comments... as ur answer does not answer my question,,, now iam not able to delete this question also bcos u have ansered it,, but its not what iam looking for...